# Gave hacker my system credentials - 9 digit ID and 4 digit password - Can I change these?

Tags: security

I gave a hacker access to my computer via iexplore/supremocontrol.com.  I
gave him the ID and password, although they were visible on the screen.  I 
think they are the "system credentials" - 9 digit ID and 4 digit password.
I really don't know what I did or what can happen.  Can I change the ID and password?  What should I do?

Comment: Unplug that computer from the internet to begin with.

Comment: What you gave them can only be used if you start the program they told you to use.  What you gave them should have only been usable for a single session.  If they actually used those credentials and connected to your computer, thats something else entirety, there is no way for us to know what they did.  *Don't let strangers connect to your computer in the future.*

Comment: Did this hacker call you from a call center and told you that your system is infected by some virus, maybe with an indian accent?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add anything you remember from that session.

Answer (score 1):

If you visit the [Supremocontrol website](http://www.supremocontrol.com/) you'll see that it is remote control software that uses 9 digit IDs and 4 digit passwords:

[image]

So what you did was allowing this 'hacker' full access to the account you were using at that time. You did *not* give him some sort of *system credentials* of your account/PC.

Changing that SupremoControl ID/password combination is probably<sup>*</sup> irrelevant, someone can only access your PC again through Supremocontrol if you actually start it.

Your real issue is that you do not remember wat happened during that remote session. The hacker may have installed malware that theoretically can do everything. It can e.g. give him backdoor access to your PC, let him use your PC in a botnet, sniff your traffic, whatever.

This means the only solid advice is the same as with every hacked system: wipe it clean, install your OS and programs again, and restore your data from backups that were made *before* all this happened.

<sup>* I'm saying *probably* because one backdoor could now be a continuously running instance of Supremocontrol ;-) and then he can access your PC at will through that.</sup>

Comment: If the hacker was an unknown person, e.g. from a call center, then you can be sure that a backdoor is installed. The hacker can use this system whenever it is running.